# Deriving expression type in SML

Tags: types, sml, smlnj, ml

I'm kinda new to sml and i'm trying to understand how to derive the expression type.
I read [Deriving type expression in ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261987/deriving-type-expression-in-ml#) and I'm trying to follow what he did to derive my expression, but I can't understand one passage.

The expression I'm trying to derive is:

```
fn x => fn y => fn z => z(z(y x))
```

What I'm doing is as follow:

```
fn x : T1 => fn y : T2 => fn z : T3 => z(z(y x)) : T4
```

At this point it should be

```
T2 = T1 -> T5                       //y x
T3 = T5 -> T6                       //z(y x)
T3 = T6 -> T7                       //z(z(y x))
```

which is where I think I'm doing the mistake.

Also there should be a constraint like

```
T7 = T4 or T6 = T4.
```

I'm not sure nor clear on this point tho.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already assigned `T4` to `z(z(y x))`, so we can use it in the last equation.

```
T3 = T5 -> T6                       //z(y x)
T3 = T6 -> T4                       //z(z(y x))
```

Since  `T5 -> T6 = T6 -> T4`, it follows that `T5 = T6` and `T6 = T4`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain how T5 = T6 and T6 = T4? Is not very clear to me. Sorry I'm not sure if i'm dumb or something.

Comment: One compound thing `T5 -> T6` equals another compound thing `T6 -> T4`, their corresponding parts are equal too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a doubt about this but I solved it. Thank you.